# Concat mysql string in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I need "Concat mysql string in a bash script". thank you very much.

These data should be taken from MySQL.

I need this format. url are only "http://..........."

```
wget -O /web/$filename.mp3 $url
```

Mysql Table name: download_url

```
+------------+---------------------------+
| filename   | url                       |
+------------+---------------------------+
| 832858388  |http://www.test.com/       |
+------------+---------------------------+
| 838234455  |838234455.mp3              |
+------------+---------------------------+
| 232728495  |232728495.mp3              |
+------------+---------------------------+
| 721723738  |http://www.test2.com/      |
+------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What strings do you need to concatenate, and what do you want to do with them? Please show the result you're trying to get from that data.

Comment: I need 2000 bit coin.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I kind of understand the question. You want something like this:

```
mysql --batch --skip-column-names -e 'select filename, url from download_url where url like "http%"' | 
while read filename url
do wget -O "/web/$filename.mp3" "$url"
done
```

I guess you want to concatenate a prefix to the URL if it doesn't begin with `http:`, but I don't know what you want to put there. If you clarify the question, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: But it only worked for single url. For too many URLs do not work correctly.

Comment: I forgot to quote `$url`, that should help if the URL contains some special characters.